# How to find a decimal and increment it with perl?

Tags: perl, decimal, increment

I have a text file with the following lines:

```
B        0.00000        0.00000       -2.71570
H        0.00000        1.18000       -2.71570
H       -1.02190       -0.59000       -2.71570
H        1.02190       -0.59000       -2.71570
```

using Perl how can I find "-2.71570" and increment it by -0.1 in duplicate files.

Comment: Have you written any code? What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: I have a written a sed one-liner but I have realized sed is not good for decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this (assuming you're using bash):

```
dec=0.1; for i in {1..15}; do perl -ane 'BEGIN { $dec=shift }; print join( "\t", @F[0..2], $F[3]-$dec ), "\n"' $dec num_table.txt > file_$i.txt; dec=$(bc <<<$dec+.1); done
```

That will start with the decrement value of 0.1, and use a shell loop to create 15 new files with the last field modified by the decrement value, which is increased by 0.1 each time.  I'm not completely clear on your desired format, but maybe this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In a perl 1-liner

```
perl -pe "s/([-\d.]+)$/$1 -.1/e" foo.txt > foo.txt.1
```

Now just duplicate 14 more times, and you'll have 15 files.

Or use the following script to create 15 files at once.

```
perl -lne '
    BEGIN {@f=map {open my $fh,q{>},qq{$ARGV[0].$_};$fh} (1..15)}
    for $i (0..$#f) {s/([-\d.]+)$/$1-.1/e; print {$f[$i]} $_}
    ' foo.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately that didn't work as it has "replaced" the "-2.71570" with "-0.1" instead of incrementing it

Comment: No it doesn't.  Did you copy and paste something wrong?  The above script would output "-0.1" if you didn't include the parenthesis in the LHS, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: Hmm, I copied and pasted the code exactly as you have given it to me, I am still getting the same thing

Comment: When I first pasted this code, it might've been missing the parenthesis.  Just make sure you're using exactly as it's in the answer right now and it should work, just replacing the filenames to their appropriate values.

Comment: Added a new version to create 15 files at once.

Comment: FYI, Jeanno is right. The first example will not work as intended, because of the use of double quote and thus the shell will interpolate the perl $ sign, which is not what you want. Instead use single quote like this and it will work as intended: `perl -pe 's/([-\d.]+)$/$1 -.1/e' foo.txt > foo.txt.1`